# How to ensure cloned hard-drive is not traceable to original

Tags: hard-drive, ip-address, disk-cloning, internet-security

I need help understanding what identifying information on a cloned hard drive needs to be changed in order to remove any trace back to the original hard drive.

I would think the IP address and MAC address are easy to change, but don't know much about what other information could be paired with the original.

I am hoping to keep most software intact, though some of the software is used for device reporting (ie performance, credential management, etc) so I imagine some needs to be uninstalled or just have metadata erased.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? The IP and MAC aren't generally stored on the hard disk... Depending on the original usage, you may have _many thousands_ of files that trace back to the original system / owner - documents, software licenses, personal files, temporary browser files, etc... Most operating systems and many applications will also produce a unique "_system ID_".

Comment: @Attie basically I want to preserve some of the hard drive setup to avoid certain re-registration/installation of a few key programs. The rest of the hard drive contents can be wiped. I want the device to appear as a different machine, the clone will go into a same model laptop as first. I probably cant get rid of all traceable information but I want to rid most. There is not much activity on the original device other than usage of a few apps. Things like personal files, documents, temp browser files I imagine would be easy to locate and delete?

Comment: What operating system are you cloning?  There are plenty of tools available to create an image of a fresh machine, which is your best bet.  Cloning after the fact results in the predicament you are in now.  Can you do a fresh build and then clone the disk?  Also understanding the notes about software licensing...  This really isn't a trivial task, in any case.

Comment: @squillman it is a windows 10 machine. The goal here is to keep some licensed software functional, but change some basic identifying IDs like mac address, IP address, volume numbers, or whatever, that would be routinely checked as part of a cursory glance to identify the machine. If someone really wants to go digging im sure they can trace back but Im not rly concerned about that. So barring software purchased separately from whats included in Windows 10, what needs to be changed to do a rough de-identification process?

Comment: My point was, it's too big of a task to comprehensively detail all that needs to change and that you should invest in a tool that has already solved this problem.

Comment: @squillman ok thats awesome,any examples of such tools i can research?

Comment: @anonymouscoder - Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope.  If you have a specific question, about how to change something specific, that question would be within scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*windows 10*" ... "*keep some licensed software functional*" ...

Cloning the hard disk likely wont help in this situation, especially if the licensing system is robust... in fact, changing the system "*in order to remove any trace back to the original hard drive*" will likely only compound this issue further and make it even less likely to work afterwards.

As an example, just changing enough individual physical pieces of hardware will typically cause Windows activation to reset, and that's quite probably true for the other (as yet unnamed) software too. Licensing systems will also often produce a unique System ID or fingerprint that is used to validate the installed license, and removing or altering that will immediately invalidate things.

Components (CPU, hard disk, mainboard) all have identifiable information like serial numbers, which are rolled into many licensing systems - it's about more than just the files being on the disk, the software working, and taking a copy of the disk.

Your best route here is likely a fresh install on the new computer, paired with open conversation with the software vendor about moving the license. If that's not an option (i.e: because they don't exist any more), then you may be in for a painful rethink. Emulating the original hardware and maintaining an exact clone of the old system *might* be an option, but it's not a straightforward route, and many licensing systems are able to trivially detect and reject virtualization.

Signficant time and energy has been invested into these licensing systems to ensure that it's not possible to do exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A hard disk contains data in the form of 0's and 1's and a lookup table where a file begins and ends.

There is no data such as an IP address or MAC address directly stored as metadata to the hard disk.

A hard disk can have a controller, and this controller will have an Identification number. A cloning operation will not change any data on the controller however, only the raw data will.

The raw data can however be a clone of the Operating System, and in there, it can have traces of the origin. It will have the IP address and MAC address etc stored in there, along other things.

If it is your goal to use the new disk in a computer that cannot be traced back to another computer, but you want to keep the files on that disk, you will have to preform a clean installation of windows, and then manually copy over the files. Note that if you install windows in your own network, you will still have the IP address and MAC address set. The MAC address is an identifier for that network card, and the IP Address, if DHCP is enabled, will be refreshed if the computer moves to a new network. Neither should be of any concern for you to change.

---

**Edit**: your latest comment suggest you actually want a full clone of the drive, to keep the programs running. These programs will have some kind of protection build-in but may check its activity based on a hardware ID that is composed on different things, such as what CPU, Motherboard, amount of RAM and other factors are present in a system. If any hardware changes, the program may see this as a new computer.

Consult the software reseller to help you reactivate when transferring the license from an old computer to a new computer. They often have a procedure to unlicense an old computer, then transfer it to the new one and get it activated without you paying for a new license.

Comment: The alternative to a clean install, is to create a Windows Image, from the installation in question. This of course would not bypass any activation restrictions licensed applications might or might not have. Your two goals are fairly inclusive to one another, in order for licensed software, to continue to be activated on multiple machines.  You have to clone not only the HDD which contains the activation state, but also have similar hardware, as to avoid the activation state being changed.